# private IP address range for GCP Cloud SQL is ignored

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I've been trying to set up Google Cloud SQL with a private IP connection, where
the IP range it's bound to is manually allocated, and have not succeeded.  I
don't know if this is a bug in the implementation because it's still in beta, if
there's something missing from the docs, or if I'm just doing something wrong.
(A command-line session is at the bottom, for a quick summary of what I'm
seeing.)

Initially, I set it up to automatically allocate the IP range.  It all worked
just fine, except that it chose 172.17.0.0/24, which is one of the networks
managed by docker on my GCE instance, so I couldn't connect from there (but
could on another machine without docker).  So then I tried going down the manual
allocation route.

First, I tore down all the associated network objects that had been created on
my behalf.  There were two VPC Peerings, `cloudsql-postgres-googleapis-com` and
`servicenetworking-googleapis-com`, which I deleted, and then I confirmed that
the routing entry associated with them disappeared as well.

Then, I followed the directions at https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-services-access#allocating-range, creating 10.10.0.0/16, because I wanted it in my `default` network, which is
auto mode, so I'm limited to the low half (which is currently clear).

At that point, I went back to the Cloud SQL instance creation page, since it
should be doing the rest for me.  I checked the "Private IP" box, and chose the
`default` network.

I wasn't taking notes at the time, so my recollection may be flawed,
particularly since my experience in later attempts was consistently different,
but what I remember seeing was that below the network choice dropdown, it said
"This instance will use the existing managed service connection".  I assumed
that meant it would use the address range I'd created, and went forward with the
instance creation, but the instance landed on the 172.17.0.0/24 network again.

Back around the third time, where that message was before, it had a choice box
listing my address range.  Again, my recollection was poor, so I don't know if I
either saw or clicked on the "Connect" button, but the end result was the same.

On the fourth attempt, I did notice the "Connect" button, and made sure to click
it, and wait for it to say it succeeded.  Which it did, sort of: it replaced the
dropdown and buttons with the same message I'd seen before about using the
existing connection.  And again, the instance was created on the wrong network.

I tried a fifth time, this time having created a new address range with a new
name -- `google-managed-services-default` -- which was the name that the
automatic allocation had given it back when I first started (and what the
private services access docs suggest).  But even with that name, and explicitly
choosing it, I still ended up with the instance on the wrong network.

Indeed, I now see that after I click "Connect", I can go check the routes and
see that the route that was created is to 172.17.0.0/24.

The same thing seems to happen if I do everything from the command-line:

```
$ gcloud beta compute addresses list
NAME                             ADDRESS/RANGE    TYPE      PURPOSE      NETWORK  REGION    SUBNET  STATUS
google-managed-services-default  10.11.0.0/16     INTERNAL  VPC_PEERING  default                    RESERVED
$ gcloud beta services vpc-peerings connect \ 
    --service=servicenetworking.googleapis.com \
    --ranges=google-managed-services-default \
    --network=default \
    --project=...
$ gcloud beta services vpc-peerings list --network=default
--- 
network: projects/.../global/networks/default
peering: servicenetworking-googleapis-com
reservedPeeringRanges: 
- google-managed-services-default
---
network: projects/.../global/networks/default
peering: cloudsql-postgres-googleapis-com
reservedPeeringRanges:
- google-managed-services-default
$ gcloud beta compute routes list
NAME                            NETWORK      DEST_RANGE     NEXT_HOP                          PRIORITY
peering-route-ad7b64a0841426ea  default      172.17.0.0/24  cloudsql-postgres-googleapis-com  1000
```

So now I'm not sure what else to try.  Is there some state I didn't think to clear?  How is the route supposed to be connected to the address range?  Why is it creating two peerings when I only asked for one?  If I were to create a route manually to the right address range, I presume that wouldn't work, because the Postgres endpoint would still be at the wrong address.

(Yes, I could reconfigure docker, but I'd rather not.)

Comment: On the recommendation of a friend who managed to get this same thing working on AWS, I tried connecting it to a VPC other than `default`, and it worked: I got the 10.x.0.0/16 network I wanted. It didn't give me a choice of address range (I only created one), but said it would use the existing one with the same message as in my question. Interestingly, after running `vpc-peerings connect`, the `cloudsql-postgres-googleapis-com` peering didn't exist yet, unlike for the `default` network; it didn't show up until the DB was created. Maybe that's part of the problem?

Comment: Another experiment: creating a new address range for the other VPC, `vpc-peerings connect` ended up connecting it to the first address range, despite my explicitly telling it to use the new one. So it looks like it just uses the first one created, regardless of what it's told.

Answer (score 4):

I found here https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/private-ip that this seems to be the correct behaviour:

After you have established a private services access connection, and created a Cloud SQL instance with private IP configured for that connection, the corresponding (internal) subnet and range used by the Cloud SQL service cannot be modified or deleted. This is true even if you delete the peering and your IP range. After the internal configuration is established, any Cloud SQL instance created in that same region and configured for private IP uses the original internal configuration.

Comment: Seeing this was a real WTF moment for me.  Now I have to live with the horrible IP range chosen automatically by some auto-create wizard unless I want to create an entirely new network

Answer (score 0):

There turned out to be a bug somewhere in the service machinery of Google Cloud, which is now fixed. For reference, see the conversation at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/118849070.